# Ionic with vueJS project "the web assets directory (./public) must contain an index.html file" error when adding capacitor

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, capacitor

I have a Ionic with vueJS project that I'm trying to make native via capacitor, when I try to run:

```
npx cap add android
```

I always receive this error message:

> the web assets directory (./public) must contain an index.html file

My project does not have and index.html file and I don't know if I can add one.

This is the full error I receive:

```
$ ionic capacitor add android
> npm i -E @capacitor/android@5.3.0

up to date, audited 700 packages in 5s

106 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

2 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
> capacitor add android
[capacitor] ✔ Adding native android project in android in 32.10ms
[capacitor] ✔ add in 32.73ms
[capacitor] ✖ copy android - failed!
[capacitor] [error] The web assets directory (./src) must contain an index.html file.
[capacitor]         It will be the entry point for the web portion of the Capacitor app.
[capacitor] ✔ Updating Android plugins in 11.43ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@5.0.6
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@5.0.6
[capacitor] ✖ update android - failed!
[capacitor] [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../PartyPlanner/android/app/src/main/assets/capacitor.plugins.json'
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
        
        capacitor add android exited with exit code 1.
```

I've tried to follow every documentation available and also tried to build the project before adding capacitor but nothing worked.

Comment: Have you tried running `ionic build` first?